Using MOSFETs to control series-wound flipper coil
I'm trying to control a series-wound pinball flipper coil using two N-Channel MOSFETs, like this:

The switches are mechanical leaf switches. The diode D1 is part of the coil assembly, I don't know exactly which model it is.
The theory of operation is like this:

Flipper button pressed
A lot of power goes through L1 - Q1 - Q2
EOS is pulled open after a few ms
A medium amount of power goes through L1 - L2 - Q2 until the flipper button is released.

However, in practice I observe a slightly different behavior:

Flipper button is pressed
Both MOSFETs die immediately.

Given that this is my first attempt at using power MOSFETs I assume that there's some silly mistake in the design, but I don't see it. Any hints?

Note that the "theory of operation" you describe is a pretty common thing--you can just call it a (solenoid/relay) economizer and people will know what you mean.

The most obvious issue is that you're driving the MOSFET gates with an extremely large gate resistor. You need to drive them with a proper drive circuit to get them to turn on quickly without blowing them up from overly slow turn-on.
The other major issue is that, because of the first issue, your gate pull-down resistors mean that there will never be 12 V at the gate--for instance, look at Q2's pulldown. It's in parallel with R2 when the switch is closed, so it changes the divider ratio of R1/R2, and since it's of the same order of magnitude as R1 and R2, it changes it by a lot. The actual voltage you get at Q2's gate may never be high enough to fully turn it on, even if it was fine to turn it on that slowly.
